# Android Redefinition of Resources

Tags: android, resources

I am trying to separate an application into an app project and a library project (besides moving it from Netbeans to Eclipse). The app will contain resources that are used by the library - for this, I had read on Stackoverflow that we can bundle the resources in the library project and then override them in the app project.

But when I did this, I am getting the error:
    ...\res\values\attrs.xml:5: error: Attribute "pageBackground" has already been defined

Am I doing something wrong here? Any of my assumptions is faulty?

Thanks,
Rajath

Comment: Did you create a android library project and added it to app project through properties in eclipse, if you do that library resources will be overridden by the app resources.

Comment: Yes, I added the library in Properties->Android->Library and 'Add'... is this correct, or should I also add it under the 'Java Build Path' in Properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I had similar problem when I tried to create a kind of 'configuration file' which was placed in application's resources and was meant to alter behavior of library it used. What I found working was using `getIdentifier` method from `Resources` instead of refering directly to `R` class:

```
final int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("my_resource", "raw", getPackageName());
```

You can then use the identifier as normal resource ID, e.g.:

```
if (resId > 0) {
    final InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resId);
    // ...
}
```

The idea was to handle both situations: when the file was present in app's resources or when it was not. But I think it should also work in your case of "overriding" the resources from library in application, thanks to `getPackageName` providing appropriate package name for resources' identifiers' resolving.

Comment: Thanks Xion... this is perfect.